# Make php calender (month view) with dynamic content

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop, html-table

I want to create a work calendar in php with a connection with my DB.

In the first horizontal row I want to show all the days of a specific month.
What I have now:

```
 <tr> 
                    <?php //first row for all days in a specific month (example november)
                        $date = "2017-11-01";
                        $end = "2017-11-" . date('t', strtotime($date)); //get end date of month


                        while(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end)) {
                        $day_num = date('d', strtotime($date));
                        $day_name = date('l', strtotime($date));
                        $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
                        $counter++;
                        echo "<th>$day_num <br/> $day_name</th>";
                        }
                    ?>  
</tr>
```

In the first vertical row I want to show list of all the employees. This list is also a result form my DB table **employees**.

Now the hardest part is coming, My DB gives me a start and end day when an employee works. If there is a match between an employee and start/end days he works, the cell must become red. If there is no match then the cell must be green.

The variables I have from my DB:

- $employee
- $start_date //day when he start with work
- $end_date //day when it stops with work

Can anyone help me with this connection and make a complete table. Thank you so much already.

Comment: Unless you're just doing this for class or the learning experience you should know that dealing with dates/times/calendars can get fairly complex very quickly.  There are a lot of great front end resources out there (moment.js, various calendar plugins) you can pass date data to (typically JSON) from your PHP controller, and let those do the heavy lifting.  Not trying to steer you away from a challenge, it can just be a tough road you're going down building a calendar from scratch.

Comment: @RobertWade Do you have any preferences which plugins I can best use?

Comment: Sorry, you're on your own there. Stackoverflow is not the place to ask for advice on plugins or which tools to use.  Do some research.  You'll find what's reputable.  Look for packages with active contributors.  Try it out, if you run into snags come back to SO with your code.